# Expected value of Brownian Bridge evaluated at a stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, expectation, stopping-times

Denote by $B$ a Brownian bridge process, by $B(\omega)$ a realization of it and by $B_t$ the projection to the time point $t \in [0,1]$. Now let $c < 0$ and

$$t^*(\omega) = \sup\{t \in [0,1]: B_t(\omega) \leq c\}$$ (with $t^*(\omega)=0$ if the latter set is empty).

I am now interested in the distribution of $B_{t*}$, for example what is $\mathbb E[B_{t*}]$?

More generally, I am interested in references which explore such stopping times and mainly the expected value of the process evaluated at the stopping time, in cases where for example Doob's optional stopping theorem is no longer applicable.

Comment: By definition $E(B_{t^*})=cP(t^*\ne0)$ and $[t^*\ne0]$ is the event that $B$ hits $c$ hence, by symmetry, $P(t^*\ne0)$ is the probability that the maximum of $B$ is at least $|c|$. In turn, the distribution of the maximum of the Brownian bridge is computed in quite a few stochastic analysis lecture notes. It follows from the joint distribution of the position and running maximum at a given time, of an unconditioned Brownian motion.

Comment: My suggestion would be slightly different: you could write yourself an answer connecting the dots of the indications in my comment.